# How to align vertices to another vertex per axis?

Tags: transforms, vertices

I would like to align vertices to another vertex per axis. I know of scaling reset for all selected per <kbd>s</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. However the alignment depends on other switches like proportional editing and so on which leads to lot of confusion. In Object Mode there is the nice align Object->Transform->Align Objects, I wish this for Edit Mode as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the Pivot Point to `Active Element`, then selecting the vertex you want all other verts to align to, last (the active vert has a brighter color).

[image]

Change the pivot through the 3D view window's header at the bottom:
[image]

Then you can scale in each axis to 0, and all selected vertices will align to the active vertex.